# Decryption returns 16 bytes instead of 32, why?

Tags: c#, aes, encryption

I have the following decryption method that seems to work fine except it is only returning 16 bytes instead of 32 it should I've stared at it too long and can't figure out what I've done wrong. I'm hoping a different set of eyes will help. Thanks.

```
private string Decrypt(string dataToDecrypt, string password, string salt)
    {
        //Generate a Key based on a Password, Salt and HMACSHA1 pseudo-random number generator 
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt));

        //Create AES algorithm with 256 bit key and 128-bit block size 
        using (var aes = new AesManaged())
        {
            // These two values are hard coded in Silverlight
            //aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            //aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aes.Key = rfc2898.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
            aes.IV = rfc2898.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize / 8);

            //Create Memory and Crypto Streams 
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {

                    //Decrypt Data 
                    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(dataToDecrypt);
                    cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    // cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

                    //Return Decrypted String 
                    byte[] decryptBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                    string decrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptBytes, 0, decryptBytes.Length);
                    return decrypted;

                }       // using (cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))

            }       // using (memoryStream = new MemoryStream())

        }       // using (aes = new AesManaged())

    }       // string Decrypt(string dataToDecrypt, string password, string salt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your block size is 128 bits. If you are only decoding one block, you will get 16 bytes.

Comment: Hi Yann, thanks for the input. I can't set BlockSize any bigger it does not allow it so how should it go aobut decoding more than one block?

Comment: @WillTartak: That completely depends on the cipher mode being used. ECB? CBC? CTR? XTR? CFB? What are you trying to accomplish that a higher level (and well designed) crypto API doesn't provide?